# Up-to-degree N polynomial multiplication

Tags: algorithm, polynomials

I am wondering if there are fast algorithms to do polynomial multiplication `modulo N`, i.e. given two polynomials of degree `N`,

[image: eq1]

[image: eq2]

I am interested in their product but only up to degree N, i.e.

[image: Eq3]

Note that the `k` sum only goes to `N` (not to `2N` as it would in normal polynomial multiplication). For example given

[image: eq4]

the result should be:

[image: Eq5]

I am aware that there are fast [algorithms to do polynomial multiplication](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multiply-two-polynomials-2/) but I wonder if they can be applied to the restricted polynomial multiplication I am interested in.

Comment: Just do normal polynomial multiplication and then drop all elements with n > N? Complexity is the same in both cases. Also, not exactly clear what is "modulo N"; if the resulting polynomial has a term x^5, and N=3, should that term be dropped, or changed to x^2?

Comment: The algorithm is same as full multiplication but drop all the n > N. Moreover, be aware that the complexity is same as before... (_From your example I can tell Module_N is meaningless here. You just need the terms up-to N._)

Comment: Hi --- I realize I abused the notation. By modulo N I just mean I conly care to terms up to degree N that's all.

Comment: Hi --- I realize I abused the notation. By modulo N I just mean I conly care to terms up to degree N that's all.

Comment: As you said, *mod N* is misleading, but you could write it as *mod x^(N+1)*